# Using OpenJ9 in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

although this question is not directly related to programming, it might be interessting also for others.
I use Netbeans and I want to use JDK8. Since Oracle changed it's license model, I'd like to use openJ9. So, I downloaded it, installed it, and I add it as a java platform (next to JDK 12) in netbeans. This works fine.
But somehow, I can't select the newly added platform in the "Java Platform" combobox although I see the installed platform when I open it via the "Manage Platforms" buttons.

Hm. Any ideas someone?

thanks,
Thorsten

Comment: Why are you choosing to use [**Eclipse** OpenJ9](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/) on NetBeans? Why not just use [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) instead?

Comment: AdoptOpenJDK offers pre-built packages with OpenJ9. Also why shouldn't someone give it a go. Based on their promise OpenJ9 should perform better in some scenarios  (compared to HotSpot).

Comment: @skomisa: to be hones: no clue. Will give OpenJDK a try. Just looking for a simple to use OracleJDK replacement to run a javafx application. I mean it probably will work wil JDK12 as well, but it seems to be very much efford to make it run,.

Comment: @user1119859 OK. I have used OpenJDK 10, 11 and 12 with NetBeans with no problems. Just update your question if you also get issues when using OpenJDK. Presumably you are using Apache NetBeans 11.0, right?

Comment: Using AdoptOpenJDKs J9 build for version 13+33 with Netbeans 11.1 I cannot reproduce this problem.